# How to update a field of collection efficient in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, time

I have dataset as

```
{"id":1,"Timestamp":"Mon, 11 May 2015 07:57:46 GMT","brand":"a"}
{"id":2,"Timestamp":"Mon, 11 May 2015 08:57:46 GMT","brand":"a"}
```

The expected result of data is

```
{"id":1,"Timestamp":ISODate("2015-05-11T07:57:46Z"),"brand":"a"}
{"id":2,"Timestamp":ISODate("2015-05-11T08:57:46Z"),"brand":"b"}
```

It means I want to revise the Timestamp in each row from string to ISODate
My current code is

```
db.tmpAll.find().forEach(
    function (a) {
        a.Timestamp = new Date(a.Timestamp);
        db.tmpAll2.insert(a);
    }
);
```

It runs sucessfully, but it will take couple minutes to run the code and it need to create a new collection. Is there any efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create new collection. Use the [**`collection.save`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) method to update your document.

```
db.tmpAll.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.Timestamp = new Date(doc.Timestamp); 
    db.tmpAll.save(doc); 
})
```